# Encode function signature with callback function as parameter in Solidity

Tags: solidity, abi.encodewithsignature

I would like to use low-level `call` to make calls to my contract. The function takes a callback function as an argument and I am not able to encode it.

This is my code:

```
contract B{
   event Foo();
   ...
   function foo(bytes32[10] calldata values,function(int256[] memory, bytes32[] memory) external callback){
       emit Foo();
       ...
   }

}

contract A{

    address b;
    ...

    function bar(){
       (bool success, bytes memory data) = b.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "foo(bytes32[10],function(int256[],bytes32[]))",
                myArray,
                this.callback
            )
        );
        if (!success) {
            revert("CALL Failed");
        }
    }

    function callback(int256[] calldata mapInt,bytes32[] calldata mapBytes32) external {
        ...
    }
```

I did manage to create a correct encoding using `web3`, which I compared with the signature in the ABI:

```js
var encoded = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature({
    name: "foo",
    type: "function",
    inputs: [
        {
            type: "bytes32[10]",
            name: "values",
        },
        {
            type: "function",
            name: "callback",
            inputs: [
                {
                    type: "int256[]",
                },
                {
                    type: "bytes32[]",
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
});
```

How can I accomplish this in solidity? The encoding in `bar()` does not work.

**Update:** Using the `bytes4` encoded signature below does not work either:

```
b.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(0x48160c65), myArray,this.callback));
```

Answer (score 3):

From solidity [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html#function-types):

> If external function types are used outside of the context of Solidity, they are treated as the `function` type, which encodes the address followed by the function identifier together in a single `bytes24` type.

You can calculate the the function signature with `web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature("foo(bytes32[10],function)")`. That returns `0x2729727a`.

Full example follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract B {
   event Foo(uint256 x);

   function foo(bytes32[10] calldata values, function(int256[] memory, bytes32[] memory) external callback) external {
       int256[] memory r = new int256[](1);
       r[0] = 1234;
       bytes32[] memory s = new bytes32[](1);
       s[0] = bytes32(uint256(4321));
       callback(r, s);
       emit Foo(1111);
   }

}

contract A {
    address public b;
    
    event Callback(uint256);
    
    constructor() {
        b = address(new B());
    }

    function bar() public{
        bytes32[10] memory myArray;
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = b.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "foo(bytes32[10],function)",
                myArray,
                this.callback
            )
        );
        require(success, "CALL Failed");
    }

    function callback(int256[] calldata mapInt, bytes32[] calldata mapBytes32) external {
        emit Callback(4444);
    }
}
```